# Ajax datastring not passing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to pass a value via datastring, but for some reason id is not getting through. Here the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
        $(".sourcecountry").change(function()
        {
            var id=$(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        console.log(id);
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get_seaports.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $(".selcab").html(html);

                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Console is showing that id is loaded and get_seaports.php is updating .selcab, but the $id=$_POST['id']; in that file is getting an empty value.

I have other ajax using the same type of code and its working.

What wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass strings to data, use objects instead.

```
var dataString = {id:id}
```

jQuery's ajax function will do the rest.

It converts key value pairs to the appropriate format for your request type.

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate? What do I have to change in the code?

Comment: Replace your line starting with var dataString with my line.

Comment: Glad to be of service.